# bash functions returns "command not found"

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've been trying to get this function to work without returning errors, but so far I'm unable to figure out what the problems is. I'm using $(report_home_space) to insert the contents of the functions on a small bit of hmtl but keep getting the error: **report_home_space: command not found** on line 30.

```
 report_home_space () {
          cat <<- _EOF_
                  <H2>Home Space Utilization</H2>
                  <PRE>$(du -sh /home/*)</PRE>
                  _EOF_
  }
```

I'm new to shell scripting, but I can't not find anything wrong with the syntax of the function, and the spelling seems correct. Thanks in advance.

Full script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Program to output a system information page

TITLE="System Information Report For $HOSTNAME"
CURRENT_TIME=$(date +"%x %r %z")
TIMESTAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIME, by $USER"

report_uptime () {
        cat <<- _EOF_
                <H2>system Uptime</H2>
                <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
                _EOF_
}

report_disk_space () {
        cat <<- _EOF_
                <H2>Disk Space Ulitilizatoin</H2>
                <PRE>$(df -h)</PRE>
                _EOF_
}

report_home_space () {
        cat <<- _EOF_
                <H2>Home Space Utilization</H2>
                <PRE>$(du -sh /home/*)</PRE>
                _EOF_
}

cat << _EOF_
<HTML>
        <HEAD>
                <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
        <BODY>
                <H1>$TITLE</H1>
                <P>$TIMESTAMP</P>
                $(report_uptime)
                $(report_disk_space)
                $(report_home_space)
        </BODY>
<HTML>
_EOF_
```

Comment: A few notes: (1) your whitespace is very unusual (ie. spaces after the function name between the parens); may not be invalid, but certainly not common idiom. (2) Using `<<-` is risky, as it's easy for tabs to be converted to spaces during copy/paste; safer to use `<<` and not indent the closing delimiter, ugly as that is.

Comment: Also, it would be more efficient to leave out the `cat` invocations (which all involve a `fork()`/`exec()` cycle, after all). Consider using `printf '%s\n' "<H2>System Uptime</H2>" "<PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>"` or the like.

Comment: I was just typing up a `printf` recommendation but you beat me to it.  :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy all the suggestions are dully noted. I'm following examples as I see them in the book I'm currently learning from, but I do see the benefit of `printf` over what I'm currently using. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BTW, your script works fine. Did you by any chance type it up in a Windows environment before uploading to a UNIX env?
Try running:

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

What this does is change line endings from from Windows to unix format. i.e. it strips \r (CR) from line endings to change them from \r\n (CR+LF) to \n (LF).

Also, on a HTML note, you're missing a closing tag for "< HEAD >" after your title tags.

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion, though I'm not sure it would result in the error that the OP mentioned.  From what I can see of the script, the text `report_home_space` never actually appears at the end of the line, so the only places where rogue `\r` characters could foul things up would be within the function (which would still run), or within the HTML (where it doesn't matter).  Of course, I haven't actually tested.  :-)

Comment: It would also be worth noting what options you use in `vim` to get an explicit view of what's inside the file.  A nod to `set list` in traditional vi might be good as well, in case `vim` is unavailable on the OP's system.

Comment: @rurouni88-I'm working on my Ubuntu machine, the script was typed (vim) and ran there. Thanks for the <HEAD/>sup :) I did miss that.

Comment: @ghoti-  liked the "set list" command. I usually run cat -A on the script to get this view.

Comment: Yeps, I use "set listchars=tab:>.,eol:\" and "set list," which allows me to quickly pick up if any dodgy chars are around :)

Comment: It turns out that the culprit was a tab character located at the end of my second function `_EOF_^I$`. All working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do "od -c filename" or "grep pattern filename | od -c"
to see if there are any hidden characters in there.